# creating a custom edittext with delete button

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I want to create a custom EditText which would look something like this.

[image]

I don't know how I would go about it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `custom view group`. Make a `XML` file, preferably from looking at your design, with a root of `relative layout`.  Put a section for your `buttons` at the top and then add your `edittext` at the bottom. 
Then using your `Java Custom View Group Class` you can wire(code) everything up to function as a single widget. Then just include your custom view group in your other xml layouts.

I provided you two tutorials below. Now here's a very cool trick you can do. Make your custom `XML layout`, but instead of wrapping the content in a class path tag, like `<com.vogella.android.view.compoundview.CustomViewGroup` inflate the custom xml view in the java code of your `Custom View Group Class`. Basically in the `Custom View Group Class` you'll add the below code. Check out my [Github Porject](https://github.com/virtualprodigy/CounterWidget/blob/master/counterwidget/src/main/java/com/virtualprodigy/counterwidget/CounterLayout.java) for a complete example.

```
private void inflateCustomView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_layout, this, true);
}
```

Here's two tutorials to help you understand making a custom view group. 
[Custom View Groups from The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/05/android-custom-layout/)
[Vogella Custom View Groups](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It was a bit more complicated of a solution than I was looking for.